# Subtract product values based on two consecutive dates and product, return a new column called product difference values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by

I have a below table.

[image]

Now I need output like below.

[image]

Now I need to display the product differences between the consecutive dates based on product group by. For example: in an Apple loop, the first row should return the default value of 3 and then the next row should return the difference value. Similarly, the code should work on for the next product Samsung loop. Then, the result should be passed into a new column as displayed in the required output.

I am totally new to MySQL, however, I have tried my best to use a join to get the desired output, but I have no idea from where to start. Please guide me on this new concept.

Below are my code which I have tried.

```
CREATE TABLE products (
id  numeric,
product text,
date_value DATE,
prod_value numeric);

INSERT INTO products(id, product, date_value, prod_value)
VALUES(1, 'Apple', '2018-01-22', 3);

INSERT INTO products(id, product, date_value, prod_value)
VALUES(2, 'Apple', '2018-01-23', 6);

INSERT INTO products(id, product, date_value, prod_value)
VALUES(3, 'Apple', '2018-01-24', 7);

INSERT INTO products(id, product, date_value, prod_value)
VALUES(4, 'Samsung', '2018-01-22', 1);

INSERT INTO products(id, product, date_value, prod_value)
VALUES(5, 'Samsung', '2018-01-23', 5);

SELECT
      current.prod_value,(current.prod_value - previous.prod_value) diff
FROM
      products previous
JOIN 
      products current
ON
      current.id = previous.id+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use correlated sub-query (for older version), if you are runing with newer version of `MySQL` then you can use `lag()` :

```
select p.*, 
       p.prodvalue - (select coalesce(p2.prodvalue, 0)
                      from product p1
                      where p1.product = p.product and p1.id < p.id
                            order by p1.id desc
                      limit 1
                     ) as proddiff
from product p;
```

Comment: I am getting this error when running your query in my MySQL Workbench "select is not valid at this position for this server version". How could I fix this issue? Thanks mate

Answer (score 1):

Use `lag()`:

```
select p.*,
       (p.prod_value -
        lag(p.prod_value, 1, 0) over (partition by product order by date_value)
       ) as prod_diff
from products p;
```